# How to set a custom background view properly with UiActivityIndicator

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

My app is using WKWebView to load my website. I need a UiActivityIndicator with a custom dark gray background view due to the UIActivityIndicator might be difficult to spot when it mixed up with my website's content. Previously, I followed https://coderwall.com/p/su1t1a/ios-customized-activity-indicator-with-swift to programmatically create an indicator. However, the tutorial is using default white and mine is large white with custom orange color. All I need just a backgroundView with an indicator inside of the backgroundView. Somehow it works until I noticed that the indicator is not that center and it ran off a little bit to the top left. Please see this image, [image]

It is very obvious on my iPhone 5 and so on. So, I used another approach which is using auto layout. The background view is still not working as well. Here is my auto layout setup [image: autolayout setup]

This is my programmatically part.

```
    loadingView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
    loadingView.center = self.view.center
    loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:211/255,green:211/255,blue:211/255, alpha: 1)
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    loadingIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    loadingIndicator.isOpaque = false
    loadingIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: loadingView.frame.size.width / 2.0, y: loadingView.frame.size.height / 2.0)
    loadingIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
    loadingIndicator.color = UIColor(red:232/255,green:126/255,blue:4/255,alpha:1.0)
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingView.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    self.view.addSubview(loadingView)
```

I would prefer using auto layout.

Comment: I think you need to change 2.0 to 2 in this line `loadingIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: loadingView.frame.size.width / 2.0, y: loadingView.frame.size.height / 2.0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue in either your auto layout setup nor the code you are trying.
The off-center issue actually seems to be an iOS bug when setting a custom color on a `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

You can see this for yourself.

- Drag a basic `UIActivityIndicatorView`
- Set a background color
- Set it's style to "Large White"
  [image: Default Color]
- Now set a color
  [image: Custom Color]

This doesn't happen when the style is `White` or `Gray`

---

*Tested it in Xcode 9.3 Storyboard as well as Simulator with Debug > Color Blended layers - ON*

Comment: Yes you are right. Now i noticed that. So any suggestions to fix that?

Comment: @Drew You could manually adjust the center by +2px until Apple fixes it in the next iOS version but then your indicator will go off-center again.

Comment: @Drew You could just use the white large without a custom color and not deal with this issue at all because its not in your control.

Comment: @Drew You could use the small white and splash color on it.

Comment: @Drew You could use a custom control / third-party that might even have some fancy ding-a-lings in it.

Comment: @Drew but it being an Apple control, there's little you can do to "fix" the `UIActivityIndicatorView` misbehavior and just file a bug report and let them fix their mistakes.

Comment: Alright, thank you for all your efforts. I think i will stick back to large white first until Apple fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this code

```
let loadingView = UIView()
        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        loadingView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
        loadingView.center = self.view.center
        loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:211/255,green:211/255,blue:211/255, alpha: 1)
        loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
        loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        loadingIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 37, height: 37)
                loadingIndicator.isOpaque = false
        loadingIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: loadingView.bounds.size.width / 2, y: loadingView.bounds.size.height / 2)
                loadingIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
            loadingIndicator.color = UIColor(red:232/255,green:126/255,blue:4/255,alpha:1.0)
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingView.addSubview(loadingIndicator)

        loadingIndicator.tag = 500
        for subView in loadingView.subviews{
            if subView.tag == 500{
                print(subView.frame)
                print("Bounds", subView.bounds)
            }
        }
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.view.addSubview(loadingView)
```

As per style of indicator view is whiteLarge, by default its 37 so change and check.

For auto layout :

1. Drag UIView with 60*60 width and height.(Give width,height, horizontal center, vertical center to your super view.)
2. Drag Indicator view into Your UIView.(Give horizontal center, vertical center to your view.)
3. select Indicator view set style to white large and check its frame.(37 by default and other style 20).
4. set constraints like below image.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort. I tried your both suggestions. The UIacitivityIndicator has a bug when u set a custom color on it. By default the white large and gray have no problems with it.

Comment: Issue related to color or  indicator was not center

Comment: Issue related to indicator was not center when i set a custom color on it. If the indicator is using it's default style which is gray color or large white, it doesn't has a problem with it.